# Calculating a new attribute for a polygon based on its corners

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, splitting, delaunay

i have a pointlayer with a real number as attribute named *amount*.
I want to calculate and visualize the difference of *amount* between neighbourhood points. So first I made a delaunay triangulation where the edges represent the neighbourhood relationship.

Now my problem is to calculate the mentioned 
difference for each triangle edge (e.g. as a new attribute for this edge) of the delaunay triangels.

Because I didn't find out how to split each polygon (triangle) to 3 seperate lines (edges), it would be also okay for me to make a defined calculation¹ for each polygon (triangle) based by the attribut *amount* of the 3 points/nodes/corners around.

I hope you understand what I want to do and can help me to solve this in QGIS

¹ Calculation: *New triangle-polygon attribute = (NodeA-NodeB)-(NodeA-NodeC)-(NodeB-NodeC)*

where NodeA is *amount* of node A etc...

Comment: The answer is minus 2*NodeB